# android: how to automatically run something after Activity start

Tags: android, timer

my idea is after the activity starts, a button will be automatically clicked. Meanwhile, a dialogue pops out, asking you if want to interrupt.
How can I implement this?

---

update:
What I want is to remote control my phone. Via adb am to start the app, so I want some OnclickListener will be called automatically. Also, in the UI, it provides an option to interrupt this automation.
I want the main activity start, and then Thread.sleep(5000). A dialog pops out asking you if you want automation or not. If I give an answer before that sleep ends, it will not get into automation state.

Thank you so much!

Comment: i think it can be achieved with broadcasts

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do - what are you starting automatically that the user will have the option to interrupt?

Answer (score 1):

In `onCreate`, just call `onClick` handler and give your button as an argument. Launch an `AsyncTask` inside to do lengthy operations in the background. Then simply show an `AlertDialog` for the user.

```java
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    Button launch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.launch);
    launch.setOnClickListener(this);

    onClick(launch); // Magic.
    showDialog(); // Show the interrupt dialog
}

@Override public void onClick(View v)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Wohoo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Actually, launch an AsyncTask here.
}

private void showDialog()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dlg.setTitle("Interrupt?");
    dlg.setMessage("Do you want to interrupt loading?");

    dlg.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int item)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    dlg.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int item)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Noooo...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    dlg.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I updated the original question. Could you take a look?